# R: functions to determine distance of multivariate data to normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a multivariate data and I am interested to compute the distance of complete data to multivariate normal distribution. I want to use R. I have seen some functions like shapiro-wilk test etc. But from them I can only understand if p-value  is less <0.05 it does not follow normal distribution. But I want to know how much it is far from the normal distribution. Can anyone please refer me to some functions that I can refer to for use.

Comment: Please clarfiy what distance you are asking about specifically.

Comment: @AEF  I want to know how much is the data far from being normally distributed. Be it distance or any other metric.

Comment: Well if you don't care about the exact metric, the easiest method is probably binning and a Chi-squared based approach.

Comment: @AEF Can you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: Basically you sort you data into bins and compare the number of points in each bin with the expected number under your proposed distribution. You can then use the test statistic of the Chi-squared test as metric.

Comment: @AEF It is a multivariate data with 20 variables. Sorting it. It is a bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [mqqnorm](https://rdrr.io/cran/RVAideMemoire/man/mqqnorm.html) function from the RVAideMemoire package. It shows, among others, Mahalanobis distances. From the function example:

```
x <- 1:30+rnorm(30)
y <- 1:30+rnorm(30,1,3)
mqqnorm(cbind(x,y))
```